# How to Eliminate #Error Columns in Tablix Crosstab Group

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, crosstab, ssrs-tablix, cross-join

Imagine a one-table query that accepts a year (range) as a parameter and then yields a dataset grouped by State, City, and Month, with a count of UFOs, if any, for each month.

Tie that dataset to an SSRS Tablix, with a crosstab layout:

- The Row Groups are State, City;
- The Column Group is the Month (Jan through Dec); and
- The row-column intersections are the # of UFOs sighted, if any.

PROBLEM:

If I run the (parameterized) report for one location, even one with few sightings, all goes well:  I see columns only for months with sightings.

However, if I report more than one location (say, "Albany," with daily sightings, and "Troy," with October-only), Troy's grouping will come out ugly:  If reported alone, just the October column would show, but, now, October along with 11 columns of "#Error" for the month name and a "0" for UFO count appear.

I suspect that one solution may involve some 0- or NULL-fill of missing-month data for Troy and other cities (How?), but is there some other way, via the Tablix widget, to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Where are these month names being displayed? Isn't there just one header for the entire tablix? Usually this just works. I suspect that you've got a `FIRST(...)` or some other formula somewhere you shouldn't. Look closely at what you've got for the text in the header for the month. (By cross tab, I assume you mean a tablix with both row and column groups.) I guess I'm not sure what you mean by "Troy's grouping" which turns out ugly. Maybe include a screenshot?

Comment: There's something about the "raggedness" of the data...Troy (1 month) vs. Albany (12 months)...that is causing this, I feel.  I am a new member, here, so, I don't think that I may yet post photos, but you have the right idea ("Tablix with both row [groups] and [one column] group").  I do not have any "FIRST" or other weird formulae.  Since posting, I found a way -- within the Tablix, of all places -- to solve the "raggedness" and thereby suppress the #Error columns:  I added a total (SUM) to the bottom of the column group.  For some weird reason, that was enough to correct the problem!

Comment: To understand what I was seeing wrong, imagine the months JAN through DEC listed horizontally with UFO tallies beneath each (for Albany).  Then, you look at Troy's, the next grouping down, and instead of the same line of months (or just OCT) with the October count, you see nine #Error headers, OCT, then two more #Error headers.  OCT has its proper count, and the #Error headers have 0 beneath them.

Comment: Usually headers are only at the top of the tablix, but what you are describing puts them in the middle, so I'm still confused. But sounds like you fixed this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what you're doing wrong but the matrix usually works with filling the headers correctly and leaving blanks where there is no data for a single group.

It might help if you show your design view.

**Design View:**

[image]

**Report View:**

[image]

Many of the users don't have data for previous months but at least one does so the month is displayed in the header. The blanks are where there is no data for that month/user combo.

I don't see why your report isn't working like this. If I only selected one user, then only the months that user had will be displayed.

Comment: As I mentioned, it made no sense to me, either, since your pleasing result is what I finally got after adding the summation:  Without it, all of the no-data blanks had the #Error result.  Your Tablix design looks like mine (after I added the summation).  I am chalking up the behavior to a quirk that, unfortunately, I am now unable to reproduce.